# Can the delta function be even or odd?

Tags: convolution

Say I have the function,

$$
\delta\left(\tau-\frac{T}{2}\right)\mathrm d\tau
$$
where T = $$\frac{2π}{ω}$$

Is this even or odd? Or neither?

Reason I ask is to find out whether I can cancel some cosine and sine terms for a convolution computation.

Comment: The expression looks funny. $\partial$ ?

Comment: I have no idea what your bizarre notation means

Comment: Are you trying to write $\delta (t -\frac{T}{2})\mathrm dt$? Either way, this doesn't seem to denote any function.

Comment: @Brian yes I couldn't figure out the correct notation in StackExchange for division...

Comment: @Macuser That looks like a differential, not a function. Are you simply asking whether or not the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) is even or odd?

Comment: @Brian Yes, a delayed one.

Comment: @Macuser Do you know the definitions of even and odd functions? Have you checked whether or not they apply? Please add this context to your question with an [edit]

Comment: Do you mean a Dirac delta? That's even (until you displace the spike), but is a distributional measure rather than a true function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\delta(x)$ is an even function which peaks at $x=0$ and $\delta(-x)=\delta(x)$. But $f(t)=\delta(t-T/2)$ peaks at $t=T/2$ and it is symmetric about $t=T/2$ as
$$f(T-t)=\delta(T-t-T/2)=\delta(T/2-t)=\delta(t-T/2)=f(t)$$